# Cannot load JPG image Pdfium

Tags: c#, c++, pdf, interop, pdfium

I try to do some stuff with PDF for a project. I'm trying to do some interop with Pdfium: https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/.

I want to convert a JPG image to a PDF (just for the start). So I found some resources on the web and I came to this:

```cs
///// My main file
// Create the stream
using FileStream image = new FileStream(@"test.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using FileStream pdf = new FileStream(@"test.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

// Init the library to use it
FPDF.InitLibrary();

// Create the PDF
IntPtr document = FPDF.CreateNewDocument();
IntPtr page = FPDFPage.New(document, 0, 3000, 4000);
IntPtr pageObject = FPDFPageObj.NewImageObj(document);


// Create a copy of the delegate
FPDF.m_GetBlockDelegate del = Delegates.m_GetBlockDelegate;
FPDF.FILEACCESS fileAccess = new FPDF.FILEACCESS
{
    m_FileLen = (ulong)image.Length,
    m_Param = image.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(),
    m_GetBlock = del,
};

// Create the FILEWRITE struct
byte[] buffer = null;
FPDF.FILEWRITE fileWrite = new FPDF.FILEWRITE
{
    WriteBlock = delegate (ref FPDF.FILEWRITE pThis, byte[] pData, ulong size)
    {
        if (buffer == null || (ulong)buffer.Length < size)
            buffer = new byte[size];

        pData.CopyTo(buffer, 0);
        pdf.Write(buffer, 0, (int)size);

        return true;
    }
};

// Load the image
FPDPImageObj.LoadJpegFile(IntPtr.Zero, 0, pageObject, ref fileAccess);
FPDFPage.InsertObject(page, pageObject);

// Save the PDF
FPDF.SaveAsCopy(document, ref fileWrite, 0);

// Destroy the library
FPDF.DestroyLibrary();
```

The problem is with this method: `FPDPImageObj.LoadJpegFile(IntPtr.Zero, 0, pageObject, ref fileAccess);`.
The struct has a delegate as a callback function to do some stuff (it does a sort of stream implementation in C).

Here is the code of my delegate, struct, and the implementation of the delegate:

```cs
public struct FILEACCESS
{
    public ulong m_FileLen { get; set; }
    public m_GetBlockDelegate m_GetBlock { get; set; }
    public IntPtr m_Param { get; set; }
}
public struct FILEWRITE
{
    // Must be 1
    public int version = 1;
    public WriteBlockDelegate WriteBlock { get; set; }
}

public delegate int m_GetBlockDelegate(IntPtr param, ulong position, [In] byte[] pBuf, ulong size);
public delegate bool WriteBlockDelegate(ref FILEWRITE pThis, [In] byte[] pData, ulong size);

// The implementation of my delegate in another class
public static int m_GetBlockDelegate(IntPtr param, ulong position, [In] byte[] pBuf, ulong size)
{
    // Original source code for the delegate
    //FILE* fileHandle = (FILE*)param;
    //fseek(imageFile, position, SEEK_SET);
    //fread(pBuf, size, 1, fileHandle);

    using FileStream fs = new FileStream(new SafeFileHandle(param, false), FileAccess.Read);
    fs.Seek((long)position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    fs.Read(pBuf, 0, (int)size);

    return (int)size;
}
```

The current problem is that pBuf should be a buffer to hold all the data to read. So it must be the same size as `size`. In my case pBuf has a size of 1. I have tested a C variant of my code and it works well (it reads all the data). Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fpdfview.h>
#include <fpdf_edit.h>
#include <fpdf_save.h>

FILE* pdfFile = nullptr;

int m_GetBlockImpl(void* param, unsigned long position, unsigned char* pBuf, unsigned long size)
{
    FILE* fileHandle = (FILE*)param;
    fseek(fileHandle, position, SEEK_SET);
    fread(pBuf, size, 1, fileHandle);

    return size;
}

int WriteBlockImpl(FPDF_FILEWRITE* pThis, const void* pData, unsigned long size)
{
    fwrite(pData, size, 1, pdfFile);

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    FILE* jpgFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\tcroi\\Desktop\\test.jpg", "rb");
    pdfFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\tcroi\\Desktop\\test.pdf", "wb");

    if (jpgFile == nullptr || pdfFile == nullptr)
        return 1;


    FPDF_InitLibrary();


    // Create the PDF
    FPDF_DOCUMENT pdf_doc = FPDF_CreateNewDocument();
    FPDF_PAGE pdf_page = FPDFPage_New(pdf_doc, 0, 3000, 4000);


    // Seek the stream and get the size
    fseek(jpgFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fileSize = ftell(jpgFile);
    fseek(jpgFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Create the FILEACCESS
    FPDF_FILEACCESS fileReadObj;
    fileReadObj.m_FileLen = fileSize;
    fileReadObj.m_Param = jpgFile;
    fileReadObj.m_GetBlock = m_GetBlockImpl;


    // Load the image to the PDF
    FPDF_PAGEOBJECT page_obj_image = FPDFPageObj_NewImageObj(pdf_doc);
    FPDFImageObj_LoadJpegFile(nullptr, 0, page_obj_image, &fileReadObj);
    FPDFPage_InsertObject(pdf_page, page_obj_image);


    // Create the FILEWRITE
    FPDF_FILEWRITE fileWriteObj;
    fileWriteObj.version = 1;
    fileWriteObj.WriteBlock = WriteBlockImpl;

    FPDF_SaveAsCopy(pdf_doc, &fileWriteObj, 0);

    FPDF_DestroyLibrary();

    fclose(jpgFile);
    fclose(pdfFile);

    return 0;
}
```

This code works well until I want to save the PDF, I only get a blank page, maybe I have missed something but according to example no. Here is the example: https://groups.google.com/g/pdfium/c/P73DgvJtgTs

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to `FPDFPage_GenerateContent` the page after inserting the object and perhaps also `FPDF_ClosePage` the page.

Answer (score 1):

When inserting an image, the initial size will be a minuscule rectangle of 1x1 PDF canvas units, because the object matrix defaults to `(1 0 0 1 0 0)`. You need to call `FPDFPageObj_SetMatrix()` with `FS_MATRIX(width, 0, 0, height, pos_x, pos_y)` on the pageobject.

And @jerbob92 is right, `FPDFPage_GenerateContent()` ought to be called as well.

pdfium docs could certainly be more obvious about this.
It took me a while to figure this out, too ;)